# How to pass a parameter through an angular controller to a service method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to keep my code clean, and I am noticing that this is very difficult in JavaScript. That being said, I have an angular controller which calls a couple different services:

```
surchargeIndex.controller('SurchargeIndexController', function ($scope, customerService, templateService) {
    $scope.customers = { Key: "", Value: "" };
    $scope.templates = { Key: "", Carrier: "", Service: "", RateType: "", SurchargeName: "", AccountNumber: "", RateGroup: "", OriginCountryCode: "", DestinationCountryCode: "", DomesticOrInternational: "", Zone: "", FuelType: ""}

    customerService.getTest($scope);
    templateService.getTemplates($scope, customerKey);

});
```

Services:

```
surchargeIndex.service('customerService', [
    '$http', function($http) {
        this.getTest = function($scope) {
            return $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "api/Customer/GetTest",
                })
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.customers = data;
                })
                .error(function() {
                    $scope.error = "Failed to load customers!";
                });
        };


    }
]);

surchargeIndex.service('templateService', [
    '$http', function($http) {
        this.getTemplates = function ($scope, customerKey) {
            return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "api/SurchargeTemplate/Get/" + customerKey
            })
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.templates = data;
                })
                .error(function () {
                    $scope.error = "Failed to load templates!";
                });
        };
    }
]);
```

The problem I am having is with customerKey. How do I pass that to the parameter on the click of a button:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <select ng-model="customerKey">
        <option value="{{customer.Key}}" ng-repeat="customer in customers">{{customer.Value}}</option>
    </select>
    <button id="getTemplates" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getTemplates(customerKey)">Get Templates</button>
</div>
```

I want to pass the currently selected option to the method so that I can act upon it. I am getting the error that customerKey is not defined when I run this though.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calling the service function with the $scope, you should only pass the parameters the service is using.

```
customerService.getTest($scope.customerKey);
```

and in the service:

```
surchargeIndex.service('customerService', [
    '$http', function($http) {
        this.getTest = function(customerKey) {
             console.log(customerKey);
        };
    }
]);
```

and don't forget to inject the services into your controller

```
surchargeIndex.controller('SurchargeIndexController', ['$scope', 
'customerService', 'templateService', 
 function ($scope, customerService, templateService) {
       //...
 }]);
```

also you should be using `ng-options` on your `select` tag instead of `ng-repeat` on your `<option>`  tag

Comment: What is the difference when I inject them into the controller as you have illustrated vs passing them in as parameters as I did?

Comment: @Robert the service doesn't need to know about the controller $scope. the service should be isolated and only perform a specific action. only the controller should be able to access the $scope and alter the view. it's the MVC approach.

Comment: I need to return the value I get from my service to the controller though. How would I do that without setting the $scope?

Comment: In the controller: `$scope.customers = customerService.getTest($scope.customerKey);` and just return the `value` on the `getTest()` function inside the service